# How to solve issue loading angular component with ViewEncapsulation.Native in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, shadow-dom

I have an issue loading angular component using `ViewEncapsulation.Native` in `firefox` and `edge` and `ipad chrome`, no issue on `safari on mac`, `chrome on windows`, `chrome on android`

> Error: hostEl.createShadowRoot is not a function

This is the stackblitz to reproduce the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webcomponent-polyfill

Based on other questions and answeres in stackoverflow and github, I already included `webcomponentsjs` to the project and included the javascript in `polyfill.ts`

```
npm install @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs
```

and add it as below

polyfill.ts

```
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce';
```

and still I get the same error

Comment: the function isn't supported on those browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/createShadowRoot , so it seems like the polyfill doesn't fix this.

Comment: @Krim seems ployfill was supposed to solve the issue
https://alligator.io/angular/using-custom-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @manklu, he answered it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26904) as below and it works perfect

> ViewEncapsulation.Native is Shadow DOM v0 which you must activate in Firefox (and which is deprecated as standard). Your polyfill implements Shadow DOM v1, so not the right one.
>
> If you use ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom it will work in Firefox without polyfill.